# Netbeans does not show Non English languages Properties file properly

Tags: netbeans

For some reason, Netbeans shows my Telugu text in I18N properties files in a Java Project as garbled. Does anybody know how I can fix this ?

I am using Netbeans 7.4 and yes the file is UTF-8 encoded.

The text should be

> గులుతె

Instead it is

> à°à±à°²à±à°¤à±

Answer (score 0):

Check encoding in project properties[image]

Comment: Sorry I took a while to reply, I have that set to UTF-8. I have the page directive in a jsp file with pageEncoding attribute as uTF-8 and I `file -i hello.jsp` returns `text/html; charset=utf-8`. Even then netbeans shows rectangles instead of foreign characters. `Kate` shows this page just fine.